# How to new task to existing tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, task, console-application

I'm creating task with array.
See below please:

```
Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[]
{
clientT1.UpdateCatalogBulkArticlePrices(catalogCode, data.prices),
clientT1.UpdateCatalogArticleSizesBulk(catalogCode, data.sizes)
};
```

My question is how to add new task in my `tasks` object.
Something like that:

```
tasks.add(...);
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use a `List<Task<int>>` instead of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>
{
clientT1.UpdateCatalogBulkArticlePrices(catalogCode, data.prices),
clientT1.UpdateCatalogArticleSizesBulk(catalogCode, data.sizes)
};

tasks.Add(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using Array construct in C#. By definition, size of an array  is fixed in construction. You can not add new elements to it. You need to use something like ArrayList/List for this purpose.

```
List<Task<int>> tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
tasks.Add(clientT1.UpdateCatalogBulkArticlePrices(catalogCode, data.prices);
tasks.Add(clientT1.UpdateCatalogArticleSizesBulk(catalogCode, data.sizes))
```

later.

```
tasks.Add(anotherTask);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You may need to create a **List** of Tasks :

```
var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
```

And then:

```
tasks.Add(AnotherTask);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have a fixed sized in construction a better solution would be using a list, but if you need to return an array, and you would like to use the method add, you could try something like this.

```
     var t = new List<Task<int>>();
    t.Add(clientT1.UpdateCatalogBulkArticlePrices(catalogCode, data.prices));
    t.Add(clientT1.UpdateCatalogArticleSizesBulk(catalogCode, data.sizes));
    Task<int>[] tasks = t.ToArray();
```